# Preventing splitting at apostrophies when tokenizing words using nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am using the `nltk` to split up sentences to words. e.g.

```
 nltk.word_tokenize("The code didn't work!")
 -> ['The', 'code', 'did', "n't", 'work', '!']
```

The tokenizing works well at spliting up word boundaries [i.e. splitting punctuation from words], but sometimes over-splits, and modifiers at the end of the word get treated as separate parts. For example, `didn't` gets split into the parts `did` and `n't` and `i've` gets split to `I` and `'ve`. Obviously this is because such words are split in two in the original corpus that `nltk` is using, and may be desirable in some instances.

Is there any built in way of over-riding this behavior? Possibly in a similar manner to how `nltk's` `MWETokenizer` is able to aggregate multiple words to phrases, but in this case to just aggregate word components to words.

Alternatively, is there another tokenizer that does not split up word-parts?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is actually [working as expected](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/401):

> That is the correct/expected output. For word tokenization contractions are considered two words because meaning-wise they are.

Different `nltk` tokenizers handle English language *contractions* differently. For instance, I've found that [`TweetTokenizer`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.casual.TweetTokenizer) does not split the contraction into two parts:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
>>> tknzr = TweetTokenizer()
>>> tknzr.tokenize("The code didn't work!")
[u'The', u'code', u"didn't", u'work', u'!']
```

Please see more information and workarounds at:

- [nltk tokenization and contractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351290/nltk-tokenization-and-contractions)
- [Expanding English language contractions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790188/expanding-english-language-contractions-in-python)
- [word_tokenizer separates contractions (we'll, I'll) into different words](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/401)